# Undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg in php8 with gd installed

Tags: php, apache, gdlib, php-8.1

I have updated the php version of my dedicated server to 8.1.4 and now the `imagecreatefromjpeg` function doesn't work anymore. I have enabled GD extension in `php.ini`, I have run `sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd` and restarted apache.

When I run  `php -i | grep -i gd` I get this:

```
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.2.5
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

The code that is being ran and has previously worked with php 7:

```
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

For me everything is correctly configured, there is no reason why php should not recognize the function.

I would be really grateful if somebody could help to solve this problem.

Comment: Which `php.ini` did you use? There's one for CLI and one for webservers. Does `GD` show up when you run a page with `<?php phpinfo() ?>`?

Comment: @brombeer I changed it both in `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini`. It only shows in php credits it doesn't show up as its own block. It's like it isn't even installed.

Comment: `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini`? You said you upgraded to `8.1`. `phpinfo` should tell you which `php.ini` it uses

Comment: It uses `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini` this file

Comment: how to solve this>

Comment: If your PHP 8.1 installation uses a configuration from PHP 8.0, you should fix tht. Also, did you check `phpinfo` **in a browser** to see whether gd is properly enabled?

Answer (score 2):

If perhaps you are using xampp or wampp, find your `php.ini` file,

then edit this

```
;extension=gd
```

to this.

```
extension=gd
```

there you have it.
to find the `php.ini` file open your xampp control panel, click on apache config, then select php.ini,

open it the hold ctrl-f then search for gd, then you find the extension then remove the semi-colon at the beginning of the line.